# LibreOffice Base Basic

Tags: vba

Estoy desarrollando una base de datos en LibreOffice Base y estoy haciendo los formularios que me abren informes sobre diferentes consultas que pueden interesar a los usuarios de la base de datos. Actualmente en el formulario hay que introducir un valor de material y un valor de fecha y con esos datos se genera un informe con toda la información correspondiente a ese material en esa fecha concreta.

Al desarrollar la macro que me permita hacer eso me compila bien, pero al ejecutarla en el formulario me marca que la variable objeto no está establecida en la linea SELECT...

Aquí os adjunto el código a ver si alguien puede ayudar.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

```
Sub FiltrarMaterial( Evento )

Dim oReporte As Object

Dim oConsulta As Object

Dim oForm As Object

Dim oCampoID As Object

Dim oFecha As Object

     'El formulario activo

      oForm = Evento.Source.Model.Parent    

      'Se obtiene el material   

       oCampoID = oForm.getByName("Material")

       'Se obtiene la fecha

       oFecha = oForm.getbyName("Fecha_de_Actualización")

      'Construimos la consulta en la que se base el reporte

      oConsulta = ThisDatabaseDocument.DataSource.QueryDefinitions.getbyName      ("Consulta de Seguridad")

      'Modificamos la consulta para que tome el registro actual

      oConsulta.Command = "SELECT ""Proceso.Material"", ""Proceso.Proceso"", ""Seguridad.Frases_H"", ""Seguridad.Frases_P"", ""Seguridad.CMR"", ""Proceso.Fecha_de_Actualizacion"" FROM  ""Seguridad"", ""Proceso"" WHERE ""Seguridad.Material"" = ""Proceso.IDMaterial"" AND ""Proceso.Material"" =" & oCampoID.BoundField.String & " AND Proceso.Fecha_de_Actualizacion = " & oFecha.BoundField.String 

      'Abrimos el informe

      oReporte =    ThisDatabaseDocument.ReportDocuments.getByName ("Consulta de Seguridad")

      oReporte.Open

 End Sub
```